# Compare two dictionaries with various data types as values

Tags: python, matplotlib

It is best to show by an example. I'm taking the "properties" field from a matplotlib plot. It is a dictionary with different keys and values.

```
keys = gca().properties().keys
ax1 = gca().properties()
```

Then I'm plotting something else and I take another instance

```
ax2 = gca().properties()
```

Now assuming the same keys are valid for ax2 (I think they are, since I didn't change the plot type), how can I compare each of the ax1 and ax2 values? These values are all different data types and simple comparison does not work. I've tried

```
for key in keys:
    if ax1[key]!=ax2[key]:
        print(key,ax1[key])
```

To which I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-363fb313494e>", line 2, in <module>
    if ax1[key]!=ax2[key]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I actually want to find the name and values of the fields that are different between the two plots. Is there a way to do so dealing with such a complex data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be know builtin `deepdiff` function that takes two objects and go into all their child methods to find the differences. Build your own function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `numpy` arrays do not support being converted to `bool`,
so the problem is not the `!=` comparison but the fact that the `if` statement is trying to convert the obejct to `bool` to see whether it is `True` or `False` and is this step that fails.

The trick is to check whether or not the value is an `ndarray` and if so use `.all()` or `.any()` to convert the result of the comparison to `bool`:

```
# assuming: import numpy as np
for key in keys:
    val1, val2 = ax1[key], ax2[key]
    are_different = val1 != val2
    if isinstance(val1, np.ndarray):
        are_different = are_different.any()

    if are_different:
        print(key,ax1[key])
```

Using `.any()` means that if a single entry in those arrays is different then they are considered different. Replace it with `.all()` if you want all the entries to be different.

Comment: The answer is valid, but after trying it I realized the plot properties are nested very deeply. For example, line color is at `gca().properties()['lines'][0].get_color()`. Is there a way to compare line colors of two plots (ax1 and ax2) without explicitly naming the the property? I want to compare all properties and find only those that are different.

Comment: @Theguy Yes, but if equality comparison is implemented properly in those data types the above code should compare `gca().properties()['lines'][0]` and the comparison would return `False`. If equality isn't implemented properly it will almost always return `False`.  In any case if it's not working or if you want a more detailed comparison you have to add more special cases and manually go deeper... there is no built-in "make the diff of two generic objects" in python.